# Why did TCP-BSD server stuck in read() even data receives?

Tags: tcp, server, iot, stm32, lwip

I've created a TCP server application using BSD sockets and NUCLEO-H743ZI2 development board with STM32CubeMX 5.6.0 & LwIP 2.0.3 in Keil-MDKARM.

I noticed that:

- If a client connects and sends 11 bytes or more at first, server
  receives the data correctly and `read()` responds displaying the data.
- However, if client sends the first data lower than 11
  bytes, `read()` function blocks even next received data is higher than 11 bytes, until client disconnects. After the disconnection, all the data queued is displayed.

Namely, if first data sent from a client to my server is lower than 11 bytes, event_callback for a rcvevent is not triggered until disconnection.

My aim is to make the server available to one byte reception.

I've pasted my Server task/thread below. Let me have your kind response at your earliest convenience and feel free to request other related files/libraries(lwip.h, lwipopts.h..).

Kind Regards

```
void StartTask01(void const * argument)
{
    /* USER CODE BEGIN StartTask01 */
    MX_LWIP_Init();

    /*start a listening tcp server*/
    int iServerSocket;
    struct sockaddr_in address;

    if ((iServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0) 
    {
        printf("Socket could not be created\n");
    }
    else
    {
        address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        address.sin_port = htons(80);
        address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

        if (bind(iServerSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof (address)) < 0)
        {
            printf("socket could not be bound\n");
        }
        else
        {
            listen(iServerSocket, MEMP_NUM_NETCONN);    
        }
    }
    /*server started listening*/

    struct sockaddr_in remoteHost;
    int newconn;
    char caReadBuffer[1500];
    memset(caReadBuffer, 0, 1500);

    for(;;)
    {
        /*block until accepting an incoming connection*/
        newconn = accept(iServerSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteHost, (socklen_t *)(sizeof(remoteHost)));

        if (newconn != -1)/*if accepted well*/
        {   
            /*block until data arrives*/
            read(newconn, caReadBuffer, sizeof(caReadBuffer));
            printf("data read: %s\n", caReadBuffer);
            memset(caReadBuffer, 0, 1500);
        }
    }
/* USER CODE END StartTask01 */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem that's causing this issue is that you only call `read` once on each connection. If you don't happen to receive all the data from that single call to `read` (which is entirely unpredictable), you will never call `read` on that connection again.

When you call `read` on a blocking TCP connection, it will only block if there is no data available. Otherwise, it will give you whatever data is available up to the maximum number of bytes you ask for. It will not wait for more data if only some is available. It's up to you to call `read` again if you didn't receive all the data you expected.

One your second iteration of the `for` loop, you overwrite `newconn` with a new connection. You don't close the old connection. So you have a socket leak.

Comment: Think of simple, there is nothing to do within the scope of the loop. If I call `read()`, it should give output if there is and it gives when the arrival data is more than 11 bytes. Then re-running the application for the same case fails if the arrival data is lower than 11 bytes. There should be something to do within the BSD implementation of LwIP library for my chose of MCU or else may be.

Comment: @SarpEnginDaltaban Fix the two bugs I explained and I'm almost certain your problems will go away. If not, it will at least be possible to diagnose them because there won't be major confounding issues. Your code only calls `read` once per connection, making it entirely unpredictable what you will and won't receive depending on what data happens to be available by luck at the instant you call `read`.

Comment: @SarpEnginDaltaban i am planning to buy this board, does this board have issues with existing libraries, as compared to say an F767ZI ?

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED:

The problem is, my server was listening port 80. I changed it to port 7 and thankfully bug is resolved, now read() works as expected.

This bug let me think that LwIP had problems on listening that web(80) port instead of others. There should be a some kind of discrimination between listening some spectacular ports even for unimplemented protocols.

Comment: That didn't resolve the bug. It just changed the buggy code from happening to not work under your test conditions to happening to work under your test conditions. Code with bugs in it may well work under some conditions and not others. Changing the conditions so that it happens to work without fixing the bug is a *bad* idea unless you continue to find and fix the actual bug.